# Rewrite Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front

Tags: overrides

How can I rewrite Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front? 
I have already tried the way we rewrite controllers but it is not working.
ADDED CODE

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <core>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Custom_Front before="Mage_Core">Custom_Front</Custom_Front>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </core>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: paste your code in question what you tried.

Comment: @liyakat I have added the code that I have used to rewrite in config.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The class is instantiated by name, not by magento factory, therefore you can only overwrite the whole class by copying it to `app/code/local/Mage/...`.

```
// \Mage_Core_Model_App::_initFrontController
// app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:744
$this->_frontController = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front();
```